# How to check whether a point is inside specific angle cone

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, shapes

As shown in [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdegV.jpg), assume screen as a square on the plane with its bottom-left corner at (0, 0), and its upper-right corner at (100, 100). Every point on the screen is either white or black. Initially, the progress is 0%, and all points on the screen are white. When the progress percentage, P, is greater than 0%, a sector of angle (P% * 360) degrees is colored black, anchored by the line segment from the center of the square to the center of the top side, and proceeding clockwise.

Then how to find a point is inside the cone or not for the given angle?

Comment: Please share some code to work with, otherwise any answer might be pure speculation and not meet your expectations. Check out how to post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your point into polar coordinates using [polar coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) concept. Then compare point's `r` to radius of Circle and point's `theta` to circle's arc. If both satisfies then your point is lying inside the sector.

Comment: Then if actual "r" and "theta" are bigger than the polar coordinates r and theta then it means that the point is inside the sector?

Comment: yes. if circle radius and arc angle is greater than or equal to point's radius and theta then point is inside the sector.